# AVM Deploy to remote AION kernel

Tags: blockchain, aion

I am encountering some problems when deploying my contract to the `avm` installed in one of the computers in the office. I am using a public key.

This is the error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.aion4j:aion4j-maven-plugin:0.5.3:deploy (default-cli) on project typeB: Failed deployment for contract : /home/frankovski/Documents/blockchain/TypeB/target/typeB-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar: Transaction failed: String index out of range: 43 -> [Help 1]
>   [ERROR]
>   [ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.

Is anyone able to assist, please?

Comment: Are you using IntelliJ with the Aion4j plugin?

Comment: yes the one recommended in their docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using your private key, double check if the it's the right key with `0x` prefix.

If you are using your public key, make sure that the public key-password pair can be unlocked with the node you are talking to. (The keystore file should be imported in that node)

Comment: I have done that but am getting a timeout while using port 8547 for avmtestnet. Is there another way of opening up to my web3? Telnet to the port goes successfully.

Comment: If you are using web3, you need to turn on the `rpc` port, where the port number is `8545` by default. (In your comfi.xml, its like <rpc active="true" ip="127.0.0.1" port="8545">). And I think  you may need to change `ip` to `0.0.0.0` to be able to connect to it remotely.

Comment: Wonderful! Worked like charm. Thanks a lot.